# Connect to Bitbucket without cloning

Tags: git, bitbucket

Sorry, I am still learning git so this is probably a very basic question. But how to I connect to a remote repository without cloning it so that I can commit/push to the repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `remote add`:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:your_account/your_repo.git
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this might work.

1. open a Empty folder
2. `git init`
3. `git add remote remote_name remote_address`
4. `git fetch remote_name`
5. add your change by create new one
6. `git add your file`
7. `git commit -m "commit message"
8. git push remote_name